# Include ERB in Rails Mailer Subject line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer

I would like to include the following code in the subject line for my rails mailer but cannot get it to work..What is the proper syntax for this? Thanks!

```
<%= @occasions.map{|o|o.pname+"'s "+o.name}.to_sentence %>
```

Mailer:

```
  def upcoming_deals_mail(user)

    @user = user
    @occasions = user.upcoming_occasions_with_deals
    @deals = user.upcoming_deals


    @subject = "An friendly Reminder"

    mail(:to => "#{ user.email } <#{ user.email }>", :subject => @subject)
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding double quotes (" ") instead of single (' ') did it for me

Fail:

```
mail(to: 'test@email.com', subject: 'Application for: #{@applicant.full_name}')
```

Success:

```
mail(to: 'test@email.com', subject: "Application for: #{@applicant.full_name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood you well but if all you want to do is including the specified ruby expression in your mail subject you can replace `@subject = "An friendly Reminder"` with

```
@subject = @occasions.map{|o|o.pname+"'s "+o.name}.to_sentence
```

Comment: thats fine but that gives me "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" when trying to send

Comment: That's because one of the objects in @occasions is a nil object. It has nothing to do with ActionMailer.

Comment: The undefined method is because @occasions = user.upcoming_occasions_with_deals is returning nil. You will either need to ensure that _upcoming_occasions_with_deals_ always returns at least one occasion or handle nil in the email template.